# convert C++ key/value structure to database (sqlite3)

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite, schema

I have a C++ key/value table that looks like this:

```
class kvBucket {
   ...
   map<string, kvBucket*> buckets;
   map<string, string> keyPairs;
   ...
}
class kvTree {
   ...
   kvBucket base;
   ...
}
```

I'd like to convert this from an in-memory structure to one that's implemented in a database (sqlite3).  I'm not sure how to represent the schema due to buckets being nested.  Here's example data:

```
bucket | key | value
------   ---   -----
   a      v      1
  a/b     w      2
  a/b     x      3
 a/b/c    y      4
   d      z      5
```

In the C++ structure, I have member functions that do things like retrieving a list of buckets under another bucket, or retrieving a list of key/value pairs under a bucket path, etc.  I'll need to do the same with the database.  Is there an efficient way to design the schema to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *efficient* way to represent a hierarchical relationship in a relational store. Key-value stores (you may have heard of them, they're all the rage these days) are better at it but generally don't provide SQL layers. Getting all the buckets under a certain path is going to require more than one query if you want to be able to move the buckets about (if you don't want to move the buckets ever, you could use the scheme you've got there and do a substring search on the bucket name for things like `"a/*"`).

That said, you can do it even without having each bucket store its own full path: you need a self-to-self many-many relationship mapping from `bucket` to `bucket`. You need two tables, one for the buckets and one just for the mapping. In the mapping table you have two columns, `parent_bucket` and `child_bucket`. In the `bucket` table you have three, `bucket_id`, `key`, and `value`.

Comment: Would I also need a bucket_id in the mapping table?

Comment: @Octave `parent_bucket` and `child_bucket` are both bucket IDs referring to the `buckets` table.

Comment: Would there be a third table that maps bucket names to id's?  if I went with a one table schema, what would the issue be with moving buckets - wouldn't it just be a rename of the buckets that need to be moved?

Comment: @Octave No, you don't need a table mapping names to IDs - since you have a one-to-one correspondence between those, you can have a "name" and "ID" column in the bucket table. Yes, you would need to rename *all* of the buckets if you go with the one-table method - you only have to change one row if you go with two. It's your choice which one is better.

Comment: Given a bucket, say "a/b", how would I traverse the mapping table without knowing the parent child relationship between the names "a" and "b"?  In other words, how would I know what their id's were since we're assuming the bucket table doesn't store full bucket paths?

Comment: You look up the ID of "a/b", then you look in the mapping table for `parent=<ID of a/b>`, and that would return all the direct children. Then you look for `parent IN <list you just got>`, and that gets you all the grandchildren, and so forth.